# How to make a list of all voice channels for discord.py bot

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I need a list of all voice channels in the server i saw the get_all_channels on the documentation but Im not sure how to implement it.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice%20channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through `Server.channels` checking `Channel.type` against `ChannelType.voice`

```
from discord import ChannelType

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def voicechannels(ctx):
    channels = (c.name for c in ctx.message.server.channels if c.type==ChannelType.voice)
    await bot.say("\n".join(channels))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.0.0+, you can get all voice channels via [discord.Guild.voice_channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.voice_channels):

```
@client.command()
async def channels(ctx):
    voice_channel_list = ctx.guild.voice_channels
    # ...
```